# sql 2008 hard drive configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql

I'm building out a new SQL Server 2008R2 64BIT, will be running two user database of about 20gb and 15gb, maybe 50/50 read/write, and about 210 users

Base hardware would be DL380, 48GB, and Intel® Xeon® X5660 (6 core, 2.80 GHz, 12MB L3, 95W) x 2.

I'm planning to setup hard drive configuartion as below
Raid 1 72gb SAS 10k for OS
Raid 1 146gb SAS 15k (T-Logs)
Raid 1 146gb SAS 15k (TempDB)
Raid 10 146gb SAS 15k x 4 (DB Files)

I would kindly need your advise with this.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: It's probably a little bit of overkill to put TempDB on it's own RAID array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use SSD hard disk if you can for TempDB etc.